# Different path variables for root and user using sudo

Tags: linux, apache, version, sudo

I am running on Oracle Linux, and when I tried to start my Apache server with the `apachectl start` command, I received some errors.  However, when I tried to use the `sudo apachectl start` command, it runs fine.  I checked the versions for both: `apachectl -V` and `sudo apachectl -V`, and I have noticed that the two use different versions (2.2.15 with `sudo`, 2.4.4 without).

Why is this?  Does sudo use a different path when looking for commands?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll find explanations here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83191/how-to-make-sudo-preserve-path

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in your user account:

```
env | grep ^PATH=
```

Now, compare this to the output from the same command run as root:

```
sudo env | grep ^PATH=
```

Are the paths the same?

Comment: No, the two are not the same.  Does that mean that as a user, I am never running things as root?